# How do I read dependencies from requires.txt of a Python package

Tags: python

I need the dependencies because I want to add these to my RPM meta-data.

To build I use:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

When I build the package `cryptography-2.2.2` it creates a file `/src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt`

It contains:

```
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1

[:platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy']
cffi>=1.7

[:python_version < '3']
enum34
ipaddress
```

How can I read all dependencies, evaluating the expression between `[]`?

I'm using Python 2.7 (don't ask)

I need the following output:

```
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1
cffi>=1.7
enum34
ipaddress
```

I want to omit other sections like `[doc]`, `[test]` etcetera.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html ?

Comment: @ChristianSauer When I do a pip install it evaluates the expressions such as `[:python_version < '3']`. I'd like to access what has been used during the build of the package.

Comment: `pip freeze` after install gives the exactly installed versions. Not per dependency, just the whole set. Otherwise look at `pipenv`.

Comment: @ThePjot Good idea, but it also lists build time dependencies which are not runtime dependencies. I don't want the tools required to build documentation on my target system, only the minimum it needs to run. I'll check out `pipenv`.

Comment: Is this file pip compatible? Because my pip will error out with this requirements file with error `InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "u'[:platfo'"`

Comment: @TarunLalwani It is produced by `setup.py build` https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `requires.txt` is part of the [dependency metadata](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#dependency-metadata), so you can use the same tools `easy_install` uses when installing the egg. Assuming the file `requires.txt` is in the current directory:

```
In [1]: from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata

In [2]: dist = Distribution(metadata=PathMetadata('.', '.'))
```

Now you can filter all dependencies for your current platform with `Distribution.requires()`:

```
In [3]: sys.version
Out[3]: '3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'

In [4]: dist.requires()
Out[4]:
[Requirement.parse('idna>=2.1'),
 Requirement.parse('asn1crypto>=0.21.0'),
 Requirement.parse('six>=1.4.1'),
 Requirement.parse('cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7'),
 Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.7')]
```

The list would be different if I used Python 2.7:

```
In [4]: sys.version
Out[4]: '2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]'

In [5]: dist.requires()
Out[5]:
[Requirement.parse('idna>=2.1'),
 Requirement.parse('asn1crypto>=0.21.0'),
 Requirement.parse('six>=1.4.1'),
 Requirement.parse('cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7'),
 Requirement.parse('cffi>=1.7'),
 Requirement.parse('enum34'),
 Requirement.parse('ipaddress')]
```

or PyPy:

```
In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '3.5.3 (fdd60ed87e941677e8ea11acf9f1819466521bf2, Apr 26 2018, 01:25:35)\n[PyPy 6.0.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)]'

In [3]: d.requires()
Out[3]:
[Requirement.parse('idna>=2.1'),
 Requirement.parse('asn1crypto>=0.21.0'),
 Requirement.parse('six>=1.4.1'),
 Requirement.parse('cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7')]
```

Now, if you want to generate a list of requirement strings (like when you want to generate a requirements file for `pip`), convert the requirements to strings:

```
In [8]: os.linesep.join(str(r) for r in dist.requires())
Out[8]:
'idna>=2.1\nasn1crypto>=0.21.0\nsix>=1.4.1\ncffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7'
```

---

#### PEP 508

If you also want to take [PEP 508 environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) into account independent of the current platform, things can get a bit trickier, but still manageable. First, convert the requirements with env markers:

```
In [22]: dep_map_pep508 = {k: v for k, v in dist._build_dep_map().items() if k and k.startswith(':')}

In [24]: reqs_pep508 = [str(r) + ';' + k.lstrip(':') for k, v in dep_map_pep508.items() for r in v]

In [25]: reqs_pep508
Out[25]:
["cffi>=1.7;platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'",
 "enum34;python_version >= '3'",
 "ipaddress;python_version >= '3'"]
```

Now handle the platform-independent deps, these house under the `None` key in `dist`'s dependency map:

```
In [26]: reqs_no_platform = [str(r) for r in dist._build_dep_map()[None]]

In [27]: reqs_no_platform
Out[27]: ['idna>=2.1', 'asn1crypto>=0.21.0', 'six>=1.4.1', 'cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7']
```

Combine both lists to a string ready to be written to requirements file:

```
In [28]: os.linesep.join(reqs_no_platform + reqs_pep508)
Out[28]: "idna>=2.1\nasn1crypto>=0.21.0\nsix>=1.4.1\ncffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7\ncffi>=1.7;platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'\nenum34;python_version >= '3'\nipaddress;python_version >= '3'"
```

Comment: This is great. It allows me to pick up a full list after building a package. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find one working solution for the same, there might be other possibilities as well, but i think this should work on most versions

```
import pkg_resources

lines = open("requirements.txt").readlines()

load_packages = True
for line in lines:
    if line.strip().startswith("#"):
        continue

    if line.startswith("[:"):
        # this is marker, let's evaluate
        load_packages = pkg_resources.evaluate_marker(line.strip()[2:-1])
        continue
    elif line.startswith("["):
        # this is a subsection ignore it
        load_packages = False

    if load_packages and line.strip():
        print(line.strip())
```

The output of the same is below

```
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1
cffi>=1.7
enum34
ipaddress
```

If I change the `requirements.txt` like below

```
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1

[:platform_python_implementation == 'PyPy']
cffi>=1.7

[:python_version > '3']
enum34
ipaddress
```

The output changes to

```
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the beginning of each line to whether or not it is a match to the pip dependency declaration format.

Regex is probably the best solution to pattern matching:

```
pattern = r'^[\w\d_-]+'
```

Where:

- `^` matches to beginning of line/file
- `[\w\d_-]+` matches any word (`\w`), digit (`\d`), underscore (`_`), and dash (`-`) more than once.

All in all:

```
from re import match

pattern = r'^[\w\d_-]+'
with open('requires.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if match(pattern, line):
            print(line.strip())
```

Result:

```
$ python2.7 test.py
idna>=2.1
asn1crypto>=0.21.0
six>=1.4.1
cffi>=1.7
enum34
ipaddress
```

Comment: Nice. This works in most cases but, I want to omit other sections like [doc], [test] etcetera. The accepted answer covers that.

Comment: @EddyPronk My solution omits those sections but I agree, the accepted answer is what I would go with as well.